# How to send list of Image to Http post Request in .Net?

Tags: arrays, json, image, json.net, httprequest

I have list of images =  list of byte arrays like below :

```
List<byte[]> imageBytesList = new List<byte[]>();

        for (int pageId = 0; pageId < documentPageNumber; pageId++)
        {
            string preprossed_path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(document.Path) + "\\" + documentId + "_" + pageId.ToString() + "_preprocessed.tif";
            if (File.Exists(preprossed_path))
            {
                var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(preprossed_path);
                imageBytesList.Add(imageBytes);
            }
        }
```

And I want to send these list of images with json data to a http server.but I am not sure how can I put this list of byte[] to my json object. Normally, when I had one image, I would go like this:

```
var imageBytesStr = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
dict.Add("base64encoded", imageBytesStr);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

I couldn't directly convert from imageBytesList to base64 string so that I can put json dictionary. What am I missing here ?

Comment: You do not have to manually convert your byte arrays to base 64 before serializing.  Json.Net will do that for you.  Here is an example of putting a `List<byte[]>` into a `Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>>` and serializing it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NXdYuX

Comment: Thank you it helped :)